# PHP AJAX Jquery - File download issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading Via JQuery AJAX Post not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357887/downloading-via-jquery-ajax-post-not-working)

filedownload.php has below snippent.

```
$file = 'cut.png';
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
readfile($file);
exit();
```

AJAX Call

```
jQuery.post('filedownload.php',{            
  'file'  :  result  // not used for the time being                    
 });
```

I make an ajax call to the `filedownload.php` file. It does not allow user to download the file. But If I run the php directly it allows user to download the file. What could be the issue ?

I would like to use core functions rather than using jQuery Plugins. If it's not possible a plugin would be fine.

Given that I use ajax because the page can not be refreshed.

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676348/allow-user-to-download-file-using-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Problem
>
> Let's take the example of a productivity web app such as a spreadsheet
>   editor, which has the ability to open, save, import and export. The
>   open and save options would involve loading a spreadsheet from the
>   database, whereas import and export deal with local files on the
>   user's machine. To implement the export behavior, you might decide
>   that the user should have to save their spreadsheet first, allowing
>   you to export the data from the backend to file. But let's assume
>   instead you'd like to allow users to export their data without saving,
>   perhaps to afford them the option of working locally without ever
>   storing data on the server. In order to do this, you'd need to send
>   the current spreadsheet data to the backend and receive a file to
>   download. Unfortunately, this can not be handled using Ajax, since
>   Ajax can only receive responses in the form of text. In cases where
>   the data to be saved is rather lengthy, this poses a considerable
>   problem.
>
> The Workaround
>
> In order to make the request, you'd need to make a regular (not Ajax)
>   HTTP request using GET or POST. If the data is reasonably short, you
>   might get away with a GET request (perhaps by simply setting
>   Window.location to your export url), but due to varying browser
>   limitations on GET request length, a POST will most likely be needed.
>   The following plugin allows you to make a request that returns a file
>   in a similar syntax to jQuery's native Ajax functions.

jQuery Code Which fixes the problem

```
jQuery.download = function(url, data, method){
    //url and data options required
    if( url && data ){ 
        //data can be string of parameters or array/object
        data = typeof data == 'string' ? data : jQuery.param(data);
        //split params into form inputs
        var inputs = '';
        jQuery.each(data.split('&'), function(){ 
            var pair = this.split('=');
            inputs+='<input type="hidden" name="'+ pair[0] +'" value="'+ pair[1] +'" />'; 
        });
        //send request
        jQuery('<form action="'+ url +'" method="'+ (method||'post') +'">'+inputs+'</form>')
        .appendTo('body').submit().remove();
    };
};
```

How to call

```
$.download('filedownload.php','filename='+filename );
```

[***Read more***](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_plugin_for_requesting_ajax_like_file_downloads/)