# Need javascript event after returning mvc FileResult

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, dom-events

My app does a form.submit() that invokes an action that returns a FileResult  (an attachment).  Prior to submit I have javacript that puts up a "please wait" div.  I need to clear it when the result is returned.  For actions that return a response that writes the page,  I use the window.onload event to clear the div, but that event doesn't fire when an attachment is returned.

It doesn't work to do something like `form.submit();HidePleaseWait()` because submit is asynchronous.   Is there some other event that fires when an attachment is returned? Or, is there some way to combine multiple ActionResult so that I could update the page in the same response?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) you should do the following.

```
$('selector').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // @Hiding
    // Do your AJAX call
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        success: function(){
            // @What to do when done
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What would I do in the "what to do when done" block?  I know I can hide my pleasewait div, but I'd also have to handle the attachment response.  I know how to handle "normal" responses that would have me, for example, replace content, but I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Well, if you want to send a form WITHOUT reloading the page you would change it to an AJAX call. It avoid the browser from moving into the action address.

Comment: I don't think your answer addresses my problem, unless you can describe how to handle the attachment-result.

Comment: success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) You could receive data and handle it with jQuery. Just change the anonymous function to 3 arguments.

Comment: It appears that it is not possible to handle an attachment (download) response in ajax. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464665/ajax-response-content-disposition-attachment].  So, unfortunately, I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a old post, but I had the same need and found something that might interrest someone in the future.

I found the solution there : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1095434/Show-an-animation-while-waiting-for-a-download-to

I just had to add `window.clearInterval(_tmr)` to stop the verification each 100ms and `document.cookie = 'dlc= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'` to clear the cookie.

So my final code looks like :

```
var _tmr;

$('form').submit(function () {
    if (!_tmr) {
        $('#cookieValue').val(Date.now().toString());

        _tmr = window.setInterval(VerifyEnd, 100);
    }
});

function VerifyEnd() {
    var _str = 'dlc=' + $('#cookieValue').val();
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(_str) !== -1) {
        $('body').removeClass("loading");
        window.clearInterval(_tmr);
        document.cookie = 'dlc= ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
        _tmr = null;
    }
}
```