# How is the type attribute of tag a in html implemented?

Tags: html

The [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_a_type.asp) state that the "type attribute specifies the MIME type of the linked document" and provide `<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" type="text/html">W3Schools</a>` as example. If I change `text/html` to `application/zip` the `accept` header field is **not** changed.

The [explanation in the specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#links-created-by-a-and-area-elements) also states that the attribute is "purely advisory". That means, a browser can simply ignore it?

It would have expected, that the attribute is reflected in the "accept" header field.

Comment: @robertc - I guess the web page knows what resources are available at the end of the link, so the accept header could become the intersection of the resource types supported by the browser and the type(s) specified by the link. If the intersection was empty, the page could even not show the anchor as a link. Otherwise, the modified accept header could be used by the server for content negotiation purposes. Browsers don't do this, but theoretically it's how it could be useful.

Comment: URL www.example.org/data. If HTML is requested, the HTML page is displayed. If ZIP is requested, the data should be represented as compressed ZIP. The HTML page contains a link to the ZIP representation (type="application/zip"). Without pointing to a different URL (e.g., "?zip") it does not seem to be possible to do (even with JavaScript - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464665/ajax-response-content-disposition-attachment)

Comment: @koppor, completely agree. Why the `Accept` header value doesn't include the media type is baffling. Very hard for the server to give the client something it can handle if the client doesn't say what it accepts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `type` attribute, if present, gives the MIME type of the linked resource. It is purely advisory. The value must be a valid MIME type. User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use metadata included in the link to the resource to determine its type.

As it says, it's purely advisory and user agents **must not** consider it authoritative. In other words, it's not even a guarantee that it's correct and is just a *hint*. I'd think that's based purely on practicality, since links can become stale very quickly; the link cannot dictate the content of the linked-to resource. There's no other specification on what a user agent *should* do with the attribute. It could be used for example by the user agent to visually point out to the user that the link will (probably) lead to a PDF file. I am not aware of user agents that do so right now though. The attribute does not have any other specified use, so it should not change the `Accept` header either.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the spec that says the UA must change the `Accept` header to match the `type` attribute when following the link.  All it does say is that the UA must not rely on the `type` to determine the type of resource being retreived.

Answer (score 2):

The type attribute is very important with scripting and HTML5 audio/video. If you are accessing the audio/video through the HTML5 JavaScript API (e.g. to start an audio when the user wind a game) the JavaScript will fail badly if the browser is not capable of playing any of the files specified as sources for the audio/video nodes.

With JavaScript you can check if the browser is capable of playing the media before you attempt to access it, but you have to know not only the MIME type but the codecs used in the media file, and that can not be reliably guessed based upon the file extension.

That is where the type attribute comes in to play, the JavaScript can get that information from the type attribute and then query the browser if it is able to play that type of media.

The MIME type sent by the server when the media plays however still has to be correct, you can not compensate for an incorrect MIME type on the server with the type attribute, whether it is HTML5 media or any of the other tags where the attribute is used.